# Problem declaring a String array in Arduino C

Tags: arduino-c++

I'm working on a project for my engineering school, the aim of which is to program an Arduino to operate a safe.
The authentication system consists of activating a series of push-buttons corresponding to a code that is compared in a table. I have to declare the array as String because the code has to be compared with strings, but since I've changed the type from INT to String I'm getting an avalanche of errors. I don't get any errors with the CHAR type, but the problem with this type is that when you compare it with the push-button input code, it only compares the first character of the array elements.

here are the functions concerned :
'''

```
String code[15] = {'0001','0010','0011','0100','0101','0110','0111','1000','1001','1010','1011','1100','1101','1110','1111'};
char niveau[15] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O'};

bool MA5()
{
    char Lettre; // Déclarer les variables
    String ID;
    Serial.println("Entré votre lettre :");
    while (!Serial.available())
    {
    } // Entrée de la lettre de l'agent
    Lettre = Serial.read(); // Affectation
    Serial.println(Lettre);
    Serial.println("Entré Votre code par le biais des boutons poussoirs, vous avez 10 secondes");
    ID = entrer_code();
  
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    { // Vérification de l'association lettre-ID dans le dictionnaire
        if (niveau[i] == Lettre)
        { 
             Serial.println(code[i]);
            if (String(code[i]) == ID)
            {

                return true; // Association correcte
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not entirely sure how you've structured your code as I can't see the entrer_code() and your entire logic with the Serial.read

Anywho, what you are probably looking for is Serial.readString() for the ID code part.

Something like this

```
String code[15] = {"0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};
char niveau[15] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O'};

unsigned long entry_mode_started = 0;

bool entry_mode = 0; //0. niveau entry, 1. code entry
char Lettre;
String ID;

//some function that will unlock 
void unlock(bool val){
    if(val == true){
        ///// unlock
    }else{
        //// don't unlock
    }
}

void loop(){

    while(Serial.available()) {
        if(entry_mode == 0){
           Lettre = Serial.read();
           Serial.println("Entré Votre code par le biais des boutons poussoirs, vous avez 10 secondes");
           entry_mode = 1;
           entry_mode_started = millis();

        }else if(entry_mode == 1){
            entry_mode == 0;
            if(millis() - entry_mode_started >= 10000){ // taking too long
                unlock(false);
                return;
            }
            String ID = Serial.readString();
            

            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                if(niveau[i] == Lettre){ 
                    if (String(code[i]) == ID){
                        unlock(true);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            unlock(false);

        }
    
    }

}
```